# How to see the child rows

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have two entities, a User and an Organization entity. They are mapped by using one to many relationship (Orgamization (one) User (many)).
Organization:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "organization", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> users;
```

And User:

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", referencedColumnName = "organization_id")
private Organization organization;
```

When I retrieve data from an Organization, I can see the list of Users per a given organization, but when I retrieve a User, I don't see the organization details.
How could I get an organization details?

Comment: i want to retrive both table values.?

Comment: I would like to retrieve organization details when retrieving user data.

Comment: in organization table userId is foreign key right

Comment: Yes, there is a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I have added `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")`, which did the trick. I hope this is the right solution.

Comment: might be. are you seen id column in organization table.here id means user id table column

Comment: I have   Id
    GeneratedValue
    Column(name = "organization_id")
    private Long id; and  Id
    GeneratedValue
    Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

Comment: public List<Organization> getProduces(Long userId) {
            Session session = getSession();
            List<Organization> organizationList = session.createQuery("from Organization where userId="+userId+" order by Desc").list();
            return organizationList;
        }

Comment: @umapathi I believe that this can be achieved without additional code.

Answer (score 0):

From Hibernate [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy)

> By default, Hibernate3 uses lazy select fetching for collections and lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults make sense for most associations in the majority of applications.

The association your are trying to fetch is by default lazy loaded.

Now you have two solutions

1. Use `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` inside your `Organisation`
   entity.
2. Use [`JOIN FETCH`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching) to eagarly fetch your mapped entity.

Comment: Do I need to implement bot steps? Adding `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` did not help

Comment: any one should fix it.

Comment: How are you fetching the mapped entites?

Comment: I have `@JsonBackReference`, this might be an issue, I am not getting the required data after I implemented both of your solutions

Comment: That could be a reason why you are not getting your mapped entity. Try removing it.